# Does ehcache respect serialVersionUID?

Tags: java, serialization, ehcache

We're running ehcache 1.5 in a cluster with RMI replication and update servers one by one (think of a load balancer/proxy on top and zero-downtime updates).

We generally don't care about `serialVersionUID`. Trouble is, very bad things (up to an outage) can happen if you have two versions of an entity in the replicated cache. That is, if one of the servers running old code replicates an element to the new server where its class has been changed.

We typically work this around by starting new cluster for updated servers on different port, but it is quite ugly and fragile.

So, the question is: Does clustered, replicated ehcache respect `serialVersionUID` properly? That is, does it not try and replicate entities if version of the local class is different?

Thanks for the intuitive guesses, but I'm looking for as hard data as possible, official docs preferred.

Comment: Cross Post in Terracotta Forum: http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/5844.page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ehcache does not support serialVersionUID in the way you're suggesting. I have experienced the scenario you've described above first hand while running Ehcache both standalone and distributed via Terracotta where an exception will be thrown on the client if the version UIDs, do not match.

*Ideally* (and I assume this is what you're looking for) objects not matching the serialVersionUID simply would miss the cache, but unfortunately this isn't supported.

If you're looking for a slightly more graceful solution to this problem try changing the cache region name when you change your cached entity, perhaps linking it with the serialVersionUID. You'll need to update your ehcache config file to add the new cache region, however it will force resources to only request entities from caches containing the version they support. This is a big help in distributed environments where you can't update all resources with the new versions simultaneously and don't want to expire the cache.

Comment: And sorry for no external docs, but as I'm sure you've found information on this subject is sparse. Experimentation is the best policy.

Comment: What version were you using? Strangely, I got a different answer in the ehcache forum. I guess that leaves me with experiments and source code analysis.

Comment: ehcache 2.3.0. I should specify that when versionIds do not match it is ehcache that throws the exception, in agreement with the forum post.

Comment: OK, so what does exactly happen? Exception is OK (as long as it doesn't surface up to the application level). Is it possible for this situation to "pollute" cache on either node in any way? What I'm observing right now is that an entity from one node (replicated as array) is deserialized on another, and that can hurt if you removed or added a field.

Comment: My understanding is that Ehcache doesn't care what the serialVersionUID is of the Object you give it - it just dumps it into a region. When you get it out the serialVersionUID will be respected just like Java respects it i.e. if the ids don't match it will except saying the object you put in cannot be deserialized to the current object you have. -- If this exception is OK then you don't have to worry. Just know you will continue to receive it until you stop putting the old version into the cache.